# C Why does this loop through the first item?

Tags: c, list, file-io, linked-list

I'm loading in a file:

```
05 11 2014 14 53 00
AB01 52.408 -4.217
XY23 51.750 -4.300
PQ29 52.100 -6.000
NY23 52.000 -5.900
```

The first line gets put into a dateTime struct. My code is then supposed to loop through the rest of the lines, putting them into a linked list of structs. However, it creates a linked list of the same element in an infinite loop.

```
typedef struct observer{
    char id[21];
    float lat;
    float longitude;
    struct observer *next;
} observer;

printf("Please enter the name of the observer file: ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    FILE* f1 = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if(f1 == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return;
    }
    fscanf(f1, "%d %d %d %d %d %d", &dateTime.date, &dateTime.month, 
            &dateTime.year, &dateTime.hour, &dateTime.minute, &dateTime.second);
    while(fscanf(f1, "%s %f %f", temp_id, &temp_lat, &temp_long))
    {
        struct observer *new_obs = make_observer(temp_id, temp_lat, temp_long);
        insert_observer(new_obs, &observer_start);
        print_observer(&observer_start);
    }
    fclose(f1);

observer* make_observer(char *id, float lat, float longitude)
{
    observer *node = (observer*) malloc(sizeof(observer));
    strcpy(node->id, id);
    node->lat = lat;
    node->longitude = longitude;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

void insert_observer(observer *node, observer **list)
{
    observer *current;
    observer *previous = NULL;
    //int inserted = 0;

    if(*list == 0)
    {
        *list = node;
        return;
    }

    current = *list;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        if(previous != NULL)
        {
            previous->next = node;
        }
        else
        {
            *list = node;
        }
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

}
```

Comment: The code as presented doesn't even compile.

Comment: I only showed the relevant code to the problem, not my entire file

Comment: So, perhaps the issue is with `temp_id`. Oh wait, you haven't included the definition of that variable. But no worries, you're positive that it's not relevant.

Comment: Post the definition of `temp_id`, `fileName`.  It is certainly a candidate contributer to the problem.

Comment: Change `while(fscanf(f1, "%s %f %f", temp_id, &temp_lat, &temp_long))` to `while(fscanf(f1, "%4s %f %f", temp_id, &temp_lat, &temp_long) == 3)` for starters.

Comment: there is no need for that sarcasm. i was positive it was working fine since variables were being loaded properly. and since chux has fixed it, i was right about that... thanks Chux, could you post it as answer so I can upvote and accept your solution? :)

Comment: there is no need for down votes... if someone else managed to fix it,then i provided enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your insert function to this:

```
void insert_observer(observer *node, observer **list)
{
    if (*list)
    {
        observer *current = *list;
        observer *previous;
        while (current)
        {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
        previous->next = node;
    }
    else
        *list = node;
}
```

This just finds the end of the list and attaches the node to the last list item.

You also need to change the main loop `while` condition to check that the expected number of fields have been read:

```
while (fscanf(f1, "%s %f %f", temp_id, &temp_lat, &temp_long) == 3)
```

Comment: thank you :) i understand what i did wrong... i had code to insert at a middle position i think; ive been struggling with linked lists... any chance for an upvote since people are downvoting me for no reason? thanks again :)

Comment: @MaxAtkins: you were replacing the head of the list each time. Down votes might have been because the posted code does not compile (makes it difficult to replicate the problem) and poorly indented (makes it difficult to read and understand). You could at least have put the main loop of your code into `main()` and defined the variables.